# Connect MyRequestService to Reactive REST GET endpoint with Quarkus/Mutiny through callback method

Tags: java, rest, reactive, quarkus, mutiny

Last week i had my first ✨ rounds with the [Mutiny](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/) library because i needed a [Reactive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_programming) REST endpoint in my [Quarkus](https://quarkus.io/) project. This was not as obvious as it sounds so i thought i'll share my new insights about the [Mutiny](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/) library in [Quarkus](https://quarkus.io/);

Quarkus [documentation](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/quarkus-cookbook/9781492062646/) specifies the Mutiny library as the preferred library for Reactive use-cases;

[image: Going forward, Mutiny will be the preferred library within Quarkus for all things reactive.]

For example;

[image]

what stood out is that most Mutiny examples are using a new String as an example.
So, my question remained;

> how do i connect MyRequestService with Mutiny in Quarkus

This would be something as:

```
Uni<MyRequestService> lMyRequestServiceUni = Uni.createFrom().item( ... ) ...
```

MyRequestService already uses a callback structure, so I tried a callback method towards Mutiny.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mutiny](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/) uses an [Emitter](https://quarkus.io/blog/reactive-messaging-emitter/) when integrating with [callback-based APIs](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/asynchronous-synchronous-callbacks-java/);

[image: You can create a Uni using an emitter. This approach is useful when integrating callback-based APIs]

https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/getting-started/creating-unis

So MyRequestService, or an underlying callback object, needs to implement an [UniEmitter](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-reactive-messaging/smallrye-reactive-messaging/2.5/emitter/emitter.html) Consumer.
But first, to become [Reactive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_programming), my old blocking REST endpoint needs to return Uni<MyJsonResult> instead of MyJsonResult;

[image: Uni instead of MyJsonResult]

The ServiceResource just forwards the call to the Service.

[image: MyRequestService creates a MyJsonResultConsumer and delivers this to the Mutiny emitter. The resulting lMyJsonResultUni is returned to the ServiceResource]

MyRequestService creates a MyJsonResultConsumer and delivers this to the Mutiny Emitter. The resulting Uni<MyJsonResult> is returned to the ServiceResource.

[image: Finally MyJsonResultConsumer is the actual callback object; method ready() calls complete() on the UniEmitter concluding the callback towards Mutiny]

Finally MyJsonResultConsumer is here the actual callback object; method ready() calls complete() on the UniEmitter concluding the callback towards Mutiny.

Remember that Mutiny needs to provide the UniEmitter with a call(back) to accept(), so you should check for null pointers (or use a [Semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) oid). ‍♂️

Comment: For a blocking example check; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66944535/dispatch-a-blocking-service-in-a-reactive-rest-get-endpoint-with-quarkus-mutiny

Comment: For a CompletionStage / CompletableFuture API version check; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67038537/dispatch-a-completionstage-completablefuture-api-service-in-a-reactive-rest-ge