# Dispatch a blocking service in a Reactive REST GET endpoint with Quarkus/Mutiny

Tags: rest, blocking, reactive, quarkus, mutiny

Lately i've implemented a Reactive REST GET endpoint with Quarkus/Mutiny using a callback structure;

[Connect MyRequestService to Reactive REST GET endpoint with Quarkus/Mutiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66761579/connect-myrequestservice-to-reactive-rest-get-endpoint-with-quarkus-mutiny)

After finishing, I was wondering how this is settled with a call to a blocking service;

> How do i call a blocking service from my Reactive REST GET endpoint with
> Quarkus/Mutiny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't see a quick answer in the documentation, but it turned out to be quite simple;

[image]

The ServiceResource just forwards the call to the Service.

[image]

MyRequestService creates a MyJsonResultSupplier and delivers this to the Mutiny Uni with method item(). The resulting Uni is returned to the ServiceResource.

[image]

Mutiny uses method get() on the Supplier for a MyJsonResult. The call blocks with an acquire on semaphore mMyJsonResultSupplierSemaphore. Next, another worker thread calls method ready() which sets mMyJsonResult and releases semaphore mMyJsonResultSupplierSemaphore unblocking method get() towards Mutiny.

Mutiny completely hides the reactive part of the story, so you can just block on a method call within a registered supplier.

Comment: For a non-blocking example with a callback check; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66761579/connect-myrequestservice-to-reactive-rest-get-endpoint-with-quarkus-mutiny

Comment: For a CompletionStage / CompletableFuture API version check; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67038537/dispatch-a-completionstage-completablefuture-api-service-in-a-reactive-rest-ge

Comment: if you check `Thread.currentThread()` before `Uni.createFrom().item` and inside it, you will see that the thread will be `vert.x-eventloop-thread-*` for both places. So in this case you are still blocking event loop, what is bad. What you can do is to get vertx instance and execute blocking part with `vertx.executeBlocking()`, in this case it will be executed at worker thread.

Comment: Hello quit,

Any idea how to do this in the Quarkus/Mutiny context as vertx is hidden behind these?

Regards,

Roland

Comment: There is few options:
1. Use `vertx.executeBlocking()`. Quarkus is running on top of vertx, so you can inject Vertx instance in any Quarkus bean and use it. Better use `io.vertx.mutiny.core.Vertx` instance, as a mutiny wrapper of vertx, it will give you Unis results. For more details see: https://quarkus.io/guides/vertx-reference
2. Try to use mutiny `.runSubscriptionOn`. For more details see: https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/latest/guides/imperative-to-reactive/

Hope this will help