# Dispatch a CompletionStage / CompletableFuture API service in a Reactive REST GET endpoint with Quarkus/Mutiny

Tags: quarkus, reactive, completable-future, mutiny, completion-stage

After [implementing a Reactive REST GET endpoint with Quarkus / Mutiny using a callback structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66761579/connect-myrequestservice-to-reactive-rest-get-endpoint-with-quarkus-mutiny-throu) and checking [the variant with a blocking service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66944535/dispatch-a-blocking-service-in-a-reactive-rest-get-endpoint-with-quarkus-mutiny) i finally played with a CompletionStage / CompletableFuture API version;

> How do i call a CompletionStage / CompletableFuture API service from
> my Reactive REST GET endpoint with Quarkus/Mutiny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again it turned out to be quite simple (*although the underlying idea may be more complex*);

[image]

The ServiceResource just forwards the call to the Service.

[image]

MyRequestService creates a MyJsonResultCompletableFuture (*[CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) implements [CompletionStage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html)*) and delivers this to the Mutiny Uni with method [completionStage](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/guides/completion-stages)(). Another possibility would be using;

> [Uni.subscribe().asCompletionStage()](https://medium.com/@alexei.rubinov/combining-smallrye-mutiny-and-completionstage-approach-in-quarkus-ec23751578b9)

The resulting Uni is returned to the ServiceResource.

[image]

Finally MyJsonResultCompletableFuture blocks the call from MyReactiveServiceResource / MyRequestService waiting for a completionStage. Method ready() accomplish this stage and returns the MyJsonResult to Mutiny ([acting like some kind of callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66761579/connect-myrequestservice-to-reactive-rest-get-endpoint-with-quarkus-mutiny-throu)).

Comment: for the callback version check; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66761579/connect-myrequestservice-to-reactive-rest-get-endpoint-with-quarkus-mutiny-throu

Comment: for the blocking version check; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66944535/dispatch-a-blocking-service-in-a-reactive-rest-get-endpoint-with-quarkus-mutiny